# What can be the reason for broken feature and activation maps in CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, visualization

## Introduction

I am developing a convolutional neural network model for medical image classification, using TensorFlow. I have three possible classes testing simple net structure with four convolution layers together with pooling layers and some dropout. Current architecture yields acceptable results after learning process, with ~90% of accuracy, which is totally fine for me.

However, when I started trying to visualize the process of how CNN works, I stumbled upon strange net behaviour. First, I tried to look at intermediate feature maps generated after convolution layers. I implemented a function for this according to this [feature maps tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-visualize-filters-and-feature-maps-in-convolutional-neural-networks/). Solution worked, but I received something very strange.

## Results

This was the input image:

[image: CNN input image]

And the feature map after the first convolution layer I got looks like this:

[image: feature map after first convolution]

Going further, I also tried to visualize network activation heatmap to see, what are the most important regions of the image. I implemented this feature using [Grad-CAM activation maps tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/09/grad-cam-visualize-class-activation-maps-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/). And again, it works fine, but the results are odd. This time - I am getting completely black activation map after each convolution layer. This is the heatmap returned from the function that was supposed to show activation of particular image regions:

[image: activation map]

### Code for generating activation maps

As I said at the beginning, performance of the network according to some basic metrics (accuracy, precision etc.), calculated on exactly the same model, are totally fine!

## Code

```py
    import os
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import imutils
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from IPython.display import Image, display
    import tensorflow as tf
```

Here is the complete structure of my CNN:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=image_shape, 
          padding="valid"))
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
         optimizer = "adam",
         metrics = ["accuracy", "hinge", "mean_absolute_error"])
```

And training is conducted as follows:

```
early_stopping_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=5)
history = model.fit(
    train_data,
    batch_size = 16,
    epochs=32,
    validation_data = val_data,
    callbacks=[early_stopping_callback]
)
```

### Code for generating feature maps

It shows first feature map after first convolutional layer as an example (`model.layers[0]` is `"conv2d"`)

```
layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
feature_map_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, 
                                   outputs=model.layers[0].output)

example_image_normal = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
os.path.join(dataset_source, "normal", "normal_00" + 
             str(random.randrange(666, 999)) + ".png"), 
target_size=(299,299)
)

example_image_normal = 
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(example_image_normal)
example_image_normal = tf.expand_dims(example_image_normal, axis=0)

feature_maps = feature_map_model.predict(tf.convert_to_tensor(example_image_normal))
map = np.reshape(feature_maps[0][:][:], (32, 297, 297))

map = np.array(map)

plt.imshow(map[0], cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

### Code for generating activation maps

```py
class GradCAM:
    def __init__(self, model, classIdx, layerName=None):
        self.model = model
        self.classIdx = classIdx
        self.layerName = layerName
            
    def compute_heatmap(self, image, eps=1e-8):
        gradModel = tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=[self.model.inputs],
            outputs=[self.model.get_layer(self.layerName).output,
                self.model.output])
        
        # record operations for automatic differentiation
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            inputs = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
            (convOutputs, predictions) = gradModel(inputs)
            loss = predictions[:, self.classIdx]
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, convOutputs)
        
        # compute the guided gradients
        castConvOutputs = tf.cast(convOutputs > 0, "float32")
        castGrads = tf.cast(grads > 0, "float32")
        guidedGrads = castConvOutputs * castGrads * grads
        convOutputs = convOutputs[0]
        guidedGrads = guidedGrads[0]
        
        weights = tf.reduce_mean(guidedGrads, axis=(0, 1))
        cam = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(weights, convOutputs), axis=-1)
        
        (w, h) = (image.shape[2], image.shape[1])
        heatmap = cv2.resize(cam.numpy(), (w, h))
        numer = heatmap - np.min(heatmap)
        denom = (heatmap.max() - heatmap.min()) + eps
        heatmap = numer / denom
        heatmap = (heatmap * 255).astype("uint8")
        return heatmap

    def overlay_heatmap(self, heatmap, image, alpha=0.5,
        colormap=cv2.COLORMAP_MAGMA):
        heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, colormap)
        output = cv2.addWeighted(image, alpha, heatmap, 1 - alpha, 0)
        return (heatmap, output)

orig = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dataset_source, "normal", "normal_00" + str(random.randrange(666, 999))) + ".png")
resized = cv2.resize(orig, (299, 299))
                  
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    os.path.join(dataset_source, "normal", "normal_00" + str(random.randrange(666, 999)) + ".png"), 
    target_size=(299,299)
)

image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
                      
preds = custom_model.predict(image)
i = np.argmax(preds[0])

cam = GradCAM(custom_model, i, layerName="conv2d_4")
heatmap = cam.compute_heatmap(image)
# resize the resulting heatmap to the original input image dimensions
# and then overlay heatmap on top of the image
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (orig.shape[1], orig.shape[0]))
(heatmap, output) = cam.overlay_heatmap(heatmap, orig, alpha=0.5)
```

**What can be the reason for such strange behaviour? Am I missing something in my understanding of feature maps and activation maps? Is there anything wrong with network architecture itself?**

I looked everywhere and tried everything I know without success, so I will be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Have you considered that the most likely explanation is that you implemented those methods incorrectly or you missed a small but important detail? You did not include any code that generates those results, so people won't be really able to help you without more code.

Comment: I linked tutorials I used without any major changes. But you may be right, so I updated the question and included code for both feature and activation map retrieving. Hope it will be more clear now. Thanks for the suggestion!